# Sitecore Solr Search Exact Match Issue

Tags: search, solr, sitecore

Index contains fields:

- Bachelor of Arts
- Bachelor of Arts (Honours)

When search for "Bachelor of Arts" , Bachelor of Arts (Honours) is shown as first record in search result. I want "Bachelor of Arts" to be shown as first record as it is the exact match then Bachelor of Arts (Honors)

This is my solr query:

```
((_latestversion:(True) 
AND includeinsearchresults_t:(true)) 
AND ((name_t:("Bachelor Of arts"))^5 
OR pagetitle_t:("Bachelor Of arts") 
OR description_t:("Bachelor Of arts") 
OR pagecontent_t:("Bachelor Of arts") 
OR ((name_t:(*bachelor*))^2.5 
OR (name_t:(*arts*))^2.5 OR ((pagetitle_t:(*bachelor*))^2 
OR (pagetitle_t:(*arts*))^2) OR ((description_t:(*bachelor*))^1.5 OR (description_t:(*arts*))^1.5) 
OR (pagecontent_t:(*bachelor*) OR pagecontent_t:(*arts*)))))




        var pageTitlePredicatePhrase = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();
        var DescriptionPredicatePhrase = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();
        var pageContentPredicatePhrase = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();
        var NamePredicatePhrase = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();

        var pageTitle1Predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();
        var Description1Predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();
        var pageContent1Predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();
        var NamePredicate1 = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();

        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();

        //To check for the entire search phrase

        NamePredicatePhrase = NamePredicatePhrase.Or(item => item.CourseName.Equals(searchPhrase).Boost(5.0f));
        pageTitlePredicatePhrase = pageTitlePredicatePhrase.Or(item => item.PageTitle.Equals(searchPhrase));
        DescriptionPredicatePhrase = DescriptionPredicatePhrase.Or(item => item.CourseDescription.Equals(searchPhrase));
        pageContentPredicatePhrase = pageContentPredicatePhrase.Or(item => item.PageContent.Equals(searchPhrase));


        //For individual value search

        foreach (var word in terms)
        {
            Name1Predicate = Name1Predicate.Or(item => item.CourseName.Contains(word).Boost(2.5f));
            pageTitle1Predicate = pageTitle1Predicate.Or(item => item.PageTitle.Contains(word).Boost(2f));
            Description1Predicate = Description1Predicate.Or(item => item.CourseDescription.Contains(word).Boost(1.5f));
            pageContent1Predicate = pageContent1Predicate.Or(item => item.PageContent.Contains(word).Boost(1f));
        }
        Name1Predicate = Name1Predicate.Or(pageTitle1Predicate).Or(Description1Predicate).Or(pag1Content1Predicate);


        //Final Predicate

        FinalPredicatePhrase = NamePredicatePhrase.Or(pageTitlePredicatePhrase).Or(DescriptionPredicatePhrase).Or(pageContentPredicatePhrase)
                                    .Or(Name1Predicate);
```

Comment: To answer this question we need to check score of 1st and 2nd documents appearing in result. In first doc, may be there are more occurrences of "Bachelor of Arts" phrase or words *Bachelor* / *Arts*. Or length of 1st document is smaller than 2nd. Score depends on all such document characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shubhangi. But where do we add the score ? is it while building the query? My field types are ComputedIndexFields

Comment: Savitha, you may try to run query from Solr admin UI or REST API with "debug=true" parameter. E.g. http://localhost:8983/solr/films/select/?rows=20&wt=json&q=name:Fi*&debug=true

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me:

1.Created a new computed field of type string and rebuild the index.
2.Boosting the new added field

Now query looks like below:

((_latestversion:(True) AND includeinsearchresults_t:(true)) AND ((**searchname_s**:("bachelor of nursing"))^20 OR pagetitle_t:("bachelor of nursing") OR description_t:("bachelor of nursing") OR pagecontent_t:("bachelor of nursing") ))

Thanks,
Savitha